# Using MongoDB java driver with MobileFirst Platform 8 Beta JavaScript Adapter

Tags: mongodb, maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to implement a JavaScript Adapter that uses the mongodb java driver.
I've downloaded the mongodb [driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/).

The dependency in my pom.xml looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
     <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

In the implementation, I am trying to instantiate MongoClient:

```
    var mongoClient = new com.mongodb.MongoClient();
```

If I try to call the adapter, I am getting an error:

> 25.05.16 14:13:45:301 MESZ] 0000bb8c 
>   com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl E
>   FWLST0904E:  Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: getFeed in
>   adapter: MongoAdapter
>       org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage 
>   com.mongodb.MongoClient] is not a function, it is object.
>   (MongoAdapter-impl.js#20)

Seems like, the jar is not loaded properly, even though the adapter builds without errors.

I've uploaded a small sample adapter project [here](https://ibm.box.com/s/gla2hr8x4qkqnyanuupddtkhymvn20ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the sample adapter and built & deployed it to MobileFirst Server 8.0 beta. I then tested it using Swagger from the MobileFirst Console -> the adapter -> Resources. Running the getFeed procedure successfully worked.

I see that the MongoDB .jar that you're using was built using Java 8. It could be that locally you are running Java 7 and this may account for the failure.

Verify that you are using Java 8 and try again.

Comment: Thanks, building the adapter with Java 8 and running MFP on Java 8 works.